# Unable to instantiate application mono.android.app.Application...Didn't find class "mono.android.app.Application"

Tags: xamarin

My project enable the Muti-Dec option ，As soon as  refrence the xamarin binding library-Vitamio ,my app startup crashed！the error infomation as follows:

```
Forwarding debugger port 8824
    Detecting existing process
    [AndroidRuntime] Shutting down VM
    [AndroidRuntime] FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    [AndroidRuntime] Process: AnXinMe.RemoteTv.Droid, PID: 21244
    [AndroidRuntime] java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application mono.android.app.Application: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mono.android.app.Application" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/AnXinMe.RemoteTv.Droid-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/AnXinMe.RemoteTv.Droid-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    [AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:509)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4427)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:147)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1271)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    [AndroidRuntime] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "mono.android.app.Application" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/AnXinMe.RemoteTv.Droid-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/AnXinMe.RemoteTv.Droid-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    [AndroidRuntime]    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
    [AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:504)
    [AndroidRuntime]    ... 11 more
    [Process] Sending signal. PID: 21244 SIG: 9
```

Is the xamarin bug? Please help me! thanks!

Comment: What version of Xamarin.Android are you using? https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=35491

Comment: Xamarin.VisualStudio_4.0.1.147

Comment: You can workaround this via https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=35491#c5 as mentioned by SushiHangover. If you don't need to use Multi-dex, you can try to remove some large libs you don't use to get under the 65k method limit. Otherwise you'll need to apply this fix from comment 5 and comment 10: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=35491#c10